# Laravel / Livewire - conditional route with same dynamic slug

Tags: routes, conditional-statements, laravel-livewire

I have a codebase in Laravel / Livewire and would like to have the first route check if it exists and if not fallback to the second route option. Without using a redirect. This is my code;

```
Route::get('/{slug}', \App\Http\Livewire\Web\Food\Show::class)->name('food');
Route::get('/{slug}', \App\Http\Livewire\Web\Pages\Show::class)->name('page');
```

I know it would be much easier to just prefix the route but this application allows for different languages (this is defined in code not as a language selection for the user) so either English or Spanish for example and the prefixed word would then have to be translated as well. Also I think a route such as `/page/about-us` is kind of silly for a plain page.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having one route to handle both situations inside the Livewire component:

```
$food = Food::where('slug', $this->slug)->first();
$page = Page::where('slug', $this->slug)->first();

if ($food) {
  return view('livewire.web.food.show', compact('food'));
}

if ($page) {
  return view('livewire.web.pages.show', compact('page'));
}

return abort(404);
```